# Change iOS 10 notification image thumbnail size

Tags: swift, notifications, ios10

I'm new to Xcode and Swift. I'm tying to send a local notification with an image shown. I use UNNotificationAttachment to attach an image from the following code:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Testing"
content.body = "Testing rich notification"   
let attachement = try! UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "image", url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myImg", withExtension: "png")!, options: nil)
content.attachments = [attachement]    
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "TenSecond", content: content, trigger: trigger) // Schedule the notification.            
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
    if error != nil {}
}
```

I can see a thumbnail on the right side of the notification banner, but it's too small. I want to increase the size of the thumbnail so the notification look like this:

[Notification With larger thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCa2o.jpg)

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. The icon is tiny, though the source png file is more than large enough

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, iOS determines the max size.

Answer (score -1):

With iOS 10 you could use the `UserNotificationsUI` framework to replace the notification body with one that has a larger `UIImageView` for the thumbnail.
See [Customizing the Appearance of Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications) for details.